# Choose file pop up html opera gx

Tags: html

How do i remove this popup clicking choose file and instead going straight to file explorer.[image]

```
<input name="file" type="file" id="filecom">
```

Comment: Add more information and show some code to understand about your problem

Comment: That’s probably out of your control from a developer perspective and not worth worrying about. (From a user perspective, maybe use a different browser? Or look for a configuration option to turn that off.)

Comment: Semi related: You should always test your website on different browsers with different engines (mainly Firefox, Chrome/Edge, Safari), to find edge cases where an implementation only works on some browsers. While in this case there is no real problem, some features are not universal. You can generally check cross browser compatibility with [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/), as per [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#browser_compatibility) example.

Answer (score 1):

This popup is a feature of the Opera GX browser.
As you can see here: https://www.opera.com/de/features/easy-files

It is simply **not possible** for a website to have the ability to modify the browser.

It would be the same if a website could change the colour of your browser's taskbar or something similar.

Such things have to be decided by the user/client themselves in the browser settings.